# Predicting intensity of Poisson process, given event data

Tags: machine-learning, gaussian-mixture-distribution, unsupervised-learning, poisson-process, density-estimation

I have a dataset of events: each row is an event, and each column is a feature. There are millions of events and several dozen features. The features are mostly numerical (a few are categorical and I plan to one-hot encode them). One of the features is time, and I think there is a time trend.

I know the events are not perfectly independent, but I think it's too hard to model that, so as a first approximation, I'm comfortable assuming that events are generated by Poisson process with the intensity that depends on the features. I want to predict the intensity, given the feature values.

To clarify with a simple example: suppose I have the log which contains, for each accident, its time, weather data, location data, type of road, traffic conditions, etc. - in total, say 50 variables. I want to predict the intensity of car accidents given specific values for all those variables.

I expect that the true relationship between the features and the intensity is relatively smooth but quite complicated (certainly non-linear and non-monotonic). I also expect that the intensity is never negligible (that is, for any feature values, the events might still happen once in a while).

What machine learning or statistical models should I consider?

I assume kernel density estimation and other local techniques are hopeless because there are too many dimensions.

I thought Gaussian Mixed Models might help, but I haven't seen any papers or links that describe their use in a similar situation (I'm concerned that the "thin tails" of gaussian distributions would not do well given that in my data the intensity never gets too close to zero).

Comment: I didn't follow what you meant by "too many dimensions": isn't this a Poisson process *in time*, with just one dimension?  If it's not a temporal process, then please tell us in which space these events are located.

Comment: @whuber thanks - I just edited the question to add an example that I hope clarifies the problem. By the high number of dimensions, I mean there are too many variables that affect the intensity (50 in my example), and if I try to sort and group the data by time, the other variables jump around a lot even within a short time span.

Comment: But that's no problem for, say, computing a kernel density of the events *in time*.  After doing that, you have a relatively simple multiple regression problem with millions of observations, only a few dozen features, and just one response (the density): that's routine.  You have no apparent need to perform kernel density estimates in any larger space.

Comment: @whuber Let's simplify this, and say there's no time trend. Then, without conditioning on other variables, the events are generated by the Poisson process with a constant intensity. That intensity is unknown, but can be trivially estimated with a very high precision. So I'll get a constant. The problem is that I want to know the intensity *conditional* on other variables. I don't see how I can do that with just a multiple regression.

Comment: You will have identical problems in any situation where the response is a constant!

Comment: @whuber but it sounds that unsupervised learning, specifically density estimation, should be able to help. Since density conditional on other features is definitely not constant. I just don't know how to do density estimation in high dimensions. Maybe I should close this question and rephrase it as high-dimensional density estimation.

Comment: I will repeat one last time: this is *not* a problem about high-dimensional density estimation!  You have stated unequivocally that the density concerns the temporal dimension only.  Since nobody has attempted an answer, please don't close this question: just feel free to edit it so that it explains your problem as well as possible.

Comment: @whuber yeah you're right, I see what you mean. I guess the difficulty is that I'm looking for conditional density estimation rather than unconditional. Perhaps that's how I should rephrase the question.

Comment: I'm really curious in your question. You mean that the feature in your data is 50 variable? The intensity in Poisson process denotes the average of number of events, so i think you can use kernel method to estimate it. I'm in a similar case to you, but my data is on 3-dimension( t,x,y). Hope can help you anaything!